# Maven tries to deploy to malformed url when using url instead of ip

Tags: maven

I have set up a local Reposilite repository on `192.168.0.1` and have set up a redirect for it using `mvn.example.com` (both IP and url are different)

My `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    ...
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repository</id>
            <url>http://192.168.0.1:80/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

And it works fine. It deploys to address `http://192.168.0.1:80/releases/group/artifact/1.0.0/artifact-1.0.0.jar` as it should

However when I change the url to `<url>http://mvn.example.com/releases</url>` it then tries to deploy to `http://mvn.example.comreleases/group/artifact/1.0.0/artifact-1.0.0.jar`. The resulting `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    ...
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repository</id>
            <url>http://mvn.example.com/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

Which obviously fails as there is no `/` symbol between `com` and `releases`. The url `http://mvn.example.com/releases/group/artifact/1.0.0/artifact-1.0.0.jar` (with the missing `/` added) when requested from Firefox works.

The full error looks like this:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project artifact: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact group:artifact:jar:1.0.0 from/to my-repository (http://mvn.example.com/releases): Transfer failed for https://mvn.example.comreleases/group/artifact/1.0.0/artifact-1.0.0.jar: Unknown host mvn.example.comreleases: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
```

I'm using IntelliJ and the command line argument for deployment is `deploy -f pom.xml`

Comment: Please show us the POM with the non-ip-url and the Maven command line output.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have added both `pom.xml` and the command line output

Comment: Your config says `http:`, but the error message says `https:`. Is it possible that `http://mvn.example.com` has broken redirection for insecure connections? Does it work if you specify `https` directly?

Comment: @Joe yes! Changing it to `https:` made it work. There is in fact redirect there, although I wonder why this error manifested there and not around `http`/`https`